# How do I correct a directory incorrectly copied into itself?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, rename

Given the following situation...

```
<path>/mydir1/mydir2
```

...where mydir2 *should have* overwritten mydir1, but was instead placed inside, and both directories actually have the same filename. How is that fixed?

Attempting to do `mv <path>/mydir/mydir/* <path>/mydir/` or `mv <path>/mydir <path>/`  results in:

```
mv: cannot move `<path>/mydir/mydir` to a subdirectory of itself, `<path>/mydir`
```

This seems stupidly simple, but it's late here and I can't figure it out.

There are seventeen such directories to fix (path differs for each, but same mydir name).

To confirm, the error message can be caused with this:

```
# cd /path/to/directory
# mv mydir/mydir ./
mv: cannot move `mydir/mydir' to a subdirectory of itself, `./mydir'
```

Also tried:

```
# mv mydir/mydir/* mydir/
mv: cannot move `mydir/mydir/otherdir1' to a subdirectory of itself, `mydir/otherdir1'
mv: cannot move `mydir/mydir/otherdir2' to a subdirectory of itself, `mydir/otherdir2'
```

and...

```
# mv /path/to/directory/mydir/mydir/otherdir1 /path/to/directory/mydir/
mv: cannot move `/path/to/directory/mydir/mydir/otherdir1' to a subdirectory of itself, `/path/to/directory/mydir/otherdir1'
```

and using a temporary directory:

```
# mv mydir/mydir ./mydir-temp
# mv mydir-temp/* mydir/
mv: cannot move `mydir-temp/otherdir1' to a subdirectory of itself, `mydir/otherdir1'
mv: cannot move `mydir-temp/otherdir2' to a subdirectory of itself, `mydir/otherdir2'
```

I found a similar question "[How to recursively move all files (including hidden) in a subfolder into a parent folder in *nix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122233/how-to-recursively-move-all-files-including-hidden-in-a-subfolder-into-a-parent)" which suggested that `mv bar/{,.}* .` would do this.

But this also gives the same errors, as well as confusingly picking up `.` and `..` from somewhere.

```
# cd mydir
# mv mydir/{,.}* .
mv: cannot move `mydir/otherdir1' to a subdirectory of itself, `./otherdir1'
mv: cannot move `mydir/otherdir2' to a subdirectory of itself, `./otherdir2'
mv: cannot move `mydir/.' to `./.': Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move `mydir/..' to `./..': Device or resource busy
mv: overwrite `./.file'? y
```

Another similar question "[linux mv command weirdness](https://serverfault.com/questions/162037/linux-mv-command-weirdness)" suggests that `mv` doesn't overwrite and a copy is required.

```
# cd mydir
# cp -rf ./mydir/* ./
cp: overwrite `./otherdir1/file1'? y
cp: overwrite `./otherdir1/file2'? y
cp: overwrite `./otherdir1/file3'?
```

This appears to be working... except there's a lot of files (and dirs) - I don't want to confirm every one!
Isn't the `f` there supposed to prevent this?

Ok, so `cp` was aliased to `cp -i` (which I found out with `type cp`), and bypassed by using `\cp -rf ./mydir/* ./` which seems to have worked.

**Although I've solved the problem of getting dirs/files from one place to another, I'm still curious as to what's going on with the `mv` stuff - is this really a deliberate feature as [suggested by Warner](https://serverfault.com/questions/162037/linux-mv-command-weirdness/162039#162039)?**

Comment: Something doesn't add up, `mv /path/mydir /path/` tells me that "/path/mydir/ and /path/mydir are the same file"., and `mv /path/mydir/mydir/* /path/mydir/` works.  The only way I can get that "subdirectory of itself" message is if I reverse the command and `mv /path/mydir /path/mydir/mydir`

Comment: DerfK, I agree it sounds odd, but I've just run it again and will update the question with the commands...

Answer (score 1):

First, move the new directory out (with a temp name to avoid conflict), then delete the original directory, then rename the new directory into place.  Note: because this will involve deleting things en masse, think it through carefully before just running these commands, and make sure you have a backup first.  Also, I've written this with `&&`s between the commands, so if one fails the rest won't run -- good in a script, but if you're doing this manually it's probably better to just type them sequentially, pay attention, and stop if anything goes wrong.

```
mv <path>/mydir/mydir <path>/mydir-temp &&
rm -R <path>/mydir &&
mv <path>/mydir-temp <path>/mydir
```

Comment: I'm confused by the recursive delete command here - if the directory is moved why would it need to be deleted?

Comment: Also, I tried a variant of this and get the same problem - see latest edit to question.

Comment: Oops, I had the path in the `rm` command wrong; I've edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing now. This would however mean that any files in `<path>/mydir` that aren't in `<path>/mydir/mydir` would be lost. I guess sometimes that's useful, but not in this case.

Comment: Are you trying to merge the two mydir directories?  I don't think the `mv` command can do that...

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is:

```
for d in `ls -A`; do if [ "$d" != "TTT" ]; then cp -Rf $d TTT; fi; done
```

copies all directories from current directory recursively in directory TTT except TTT itself. Option `-A` in `ls` allows you to consider all hidden directories and files but don't consider special files . and .. and condition `"$d" != "TTT"` exclude directory TTT so to avoid itself copy. You may write `bash` script with 2 arguments save to local or system bin and use it when needed.

Comment: You should *never* parse `ls`. Please see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: @ChrisDown: That's true. But usually, if you are aware of the existing files on a machine you administer, directly parsing shouldn't be an issue. I have been parsing the output of `ls` on my system for a long time now, without any problems. But then I know for a fact that none of my files contain any harmful characters. In case of a new or unknown system, yes, NEVER parse the output of ls.

Comment: Considering the alternative is even shorter (`for d in *`), and more intuitive, it just seems really strange to do regardless of whether it *usually* works fine.